# Multiplying every element in a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply all the elements of this matrix by using .* but I keep getting a syntax error.
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np 

radius = 10
width = 2
randmat = np.random.rand(2,500)

R = ((radius - width/2) + width) .* randmat(1,:)
print(R)
```

Comment: Python isn't matlab. You get a syntax error because it is illegal syntax in Python. Google numpy broadcasting if you want understand how this  works in numpy

Comment: Python indexing uses `[]`, not `()`.  `randmat[1,:]`.  Syntax errors are raised by the python interpreter.

Comment: You might want to review [Numpy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).

Comment: Also `.*` isn't a python operator.  But `*` is elementwise multiplication so you don't need anything extra.  `@` is the `dot` matrix multiplication operator.